# jQuery: Can't call a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik

I had some code working with the Telerik RadGrid. When I put it on a new page, I kept getting $ is undefined ajax is undefined until I brought in the jQuery library (even though its included on the master page). I am trying to call DoUpdate when the button is pressed and get the error that its undefined.

```
 <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            function DoUpdate(sbiId) {
                var input = '{"SbiId":"' + sbiId + '"}';
                var dataSource;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.blah.com/services/testsService.svc/GetContactsDataAndCount",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: input,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        // updateGrid(data);
                        var mtv = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                        console.log(data);
                        mtv.set_dataSource(data.d.Data);
                        mtv.dataBind();
                    }
                });
                }

        });
        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>

    <p>
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClientClick="DoUpdate(1); return false" />
      </p>
```

Comment: You declared your function **inside** of another function (the `$(document).ready` callback). That makes it inaccessible. Declare it in the global scope so your button can access it. Even better, bind your event with JS, not `OnClientClick`. Don't use `$(document).ready` unless you need to and understand its purpose.

Answer (score 2):

DoUpdate is inside of $(document).ready(function() { }) - thus, anything on the outside can't access it.

Here are two ways to fix this - use jQuery to select the button and wire up the click event, or expose that function outside the ready block. Here is the latter:

```
 <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var DoUpdate;
        $(document).ready(function () {

            DoUpdate = function(sbiId) {
                var input = '{"SbiId":"' + sbiId + '"}';
                var dataSource;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.blah.com/services/testsService.svc/GetContactsDataAndCount",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: input,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        // updateGrid(data);
                        var mtv = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                        console.log(data);
                        mtv.set_dataSource(data.d.Data);
                        mtv.dataBind();
                    }
                });
                }
        });
        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>

    <p>
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClientClick="DoUpdate(1); return false" />
      </p>
```